# How do I specify a font for labelfont in caption?

Tags: fonts, captions, cjk, xecjk

I would like to set the font for the caption label, not just its series, shape or size, I would like to set the font itself. For example, my document's font is set to be Times New Roman, but I would like the caption label to be in a font that exists in another font family or even under a different font encoding. However, the `labelfont` option of package `caption` seem to only allow attributes like `normalfont`, `up`, `it`, `sl`, `sc`, `md`, `bf`, `rm`, `sf`, `tt` and so on, it would not let me specify a literal font, like Georgia, Helvetica or others.

```
\usepackage[labelfont = bf]{caption}
```

I am not sure if I have made it clear, please let me know if it is not and I will try to make it clear as possible.

Also, the reason why I am asking this question is, I am typesetting a Chinese document in which the caption label is in Chinese, but in a font I do not like. I am trying to change the font for the caption label to another font for Chinese character.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try to play with `\DeclareCaptionFormat` and similar commands described in § 4 of the documentation (‘Own Enhancements’), pp 24-28.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already using `caption` package this might be a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %jus to draw a picture
\usepackage{caption}[2007/11/04]

%select font attributes for coptions
\DeclareCaptionFont{blah}{\small\fontseries{n}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
%naturally you can define more caption fonts with different attributes to use different fonts for different kind of captions, table, figure,...

%define a different way to display "name-caption"
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{twonl}{\\[0.5\baselineskip]}

%select attributes for table caption
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=twonl,justification=centering,font=blah}

%select attribute for figure caption
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=blah}


\begin{document}

Some text, only to be able to see the font difference

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  A & B\\
  \hline
  1 & 2
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Different font for caption}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{A nice circle}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

whose output looks like:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! For my case, I used `\DeclareCaptionFont{kai}{\kaishu}` then `\captionsetup{labelfont = kai}` with package `ctex` loaded.

Comment: @zyy Great! you needed only a hint