# How to change text font to Helvetica for figure captions only

Tags: fonts, captions, fontsize, ieeetran

I am writing a journal in LaTeX in IEEE format. When I make a figure captions it is the same font as the rest of the document (Times). However, I want all the figure captions to be of type Helvetica and of size 8pt.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thepage{10.\arabic{page}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{page 1}
\newpage
\section{page 2}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to make all figure captions font Helvetica and size 8pt throughout the entire document, without changing the font and size of the main text?

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455606/118712 Although it is not very clear from the answer `phv` defines Helvetica. This is explained very well here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/118712

Comment: In terms of font size: If your document uses 11pt as the default, then `\small` is per defintion 8pt. There is an excellent conversion table here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/118712

Comment: Not `\small`, but `\scriptsize`, in 11 pt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a font for labelfont in caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455577/how-do-i-specify-a-font-for-labelfont-in-caption)

Comment: @Bernhard You are right, my mistake. It is correct in the table I linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the below modified `MWE` may helps you:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{\fontsize{9}{11}\sf\selectfont}
 \captionsetup[figure]{font=xipt,labelfont=bf}
\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thepage{10.\arabic{page}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{page 1}
\newpage
\section{page 2}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I took this from one of a suggestion from one of great `Mr Gonzalo Medina` (credits to him)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to make the such that **Fig. 1:** is not bold and that there isn't a colon after the figure number?